# How can I prune all git-lfs files except the first and last versions?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have many versions of various binary files in git-lfs. I would like to retain the last (most recent) version and the first (original) version.

For example, of any asset in my project, the latest version is the most important because it contains all of my edits. However, the original (unedited) version is often the second most important version because it enables me to reset to a clean state if I do not like the results of my edits. I typically do not care about my early edits because they are neither current nor allow me to revert to the original starting point.

**Is it possible to prune all git-lfs files except the first and last versions?**